# Ideal way to alter table so that it has minimal lock time

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, locking, alter

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1. I have a column with string datatype(varchar(255)).

My initial approach was to change the data type from string to text. but as mentioned in this article https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/11/09/postgres-alter-column-problems-and changing datatype of the column causes the entire table rewrite. and database remained locked for reading and writing while the operation happens

A Senior developer suggested me this approach. Create a new column with text datatype. this operation has very minimal lock time. Now initialize the new column with the old column. It has the row-only lock. It locks the only row which is in select for update. Now delete the old column. It is very fast and has minimal time for the lock.

My doubt is why does the first operation cause the entire table rewrite? and how is it different from second approach?

Comment: 9.1 is obsolete, consider upgrading to current version (12.2). Altering VARCHAR fields came easier in 9.2... Answer to your question "Why..." is "because of the storage technique PostgreSQL used to have when your version was made."

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen and how the second approach is better?

Comment: Your original idea was to change it to text and the senior told you to change it to text. Not knowing details of your problem, I'd suggest you change it to text. But first upgrade your Postgres.